# Why isn't my project going into debug mode?

Tags: java, eclipse

Hi i'm new to java and when I press the debug button it is not going into debug mode. 
After clicking on the drop down arrow next to the icon it says 1 new configuration and when that launches it just says in the console 'OK'. If I go on debug as it just says none applicable. 
If I go on debug configurations I don't really understand what I'm supposed to go on to get it into debug mode as i guess it is something to do with the configuration?
If it helps I'm trying to write code for a project, not android or anything like that. Hope this is enough information, thanks.

Comment: What IDE do you use?

Comment: Eclipse Luna the 32 bit version I think

Comment: First of all... are you able to run the application? If you can't run it, then you won't be able to debug it.

Comment: Yeah there are no errors in the code

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to add a breakpoint somewhere? If not, add a breakpoint! You can do that by double clicking one of the line numbers in your source code.

You may also want to check the toolbar to see if you accidentally checked the "skip all breakpoints" option.

Comment: It just says the time it took and 'OK'

Comment: But did you add a breakpoint? Do you see a blue dot beside the line number in your source code? If you don't, you don't have a breakpoint.

Comment: Perhaps you've put them in parts of the code that aren't run - put one right at the beginning of `main()`. Also, see the edit I just made.

Comment: I don't have a main method in any of my classes, is this why it isn't working? If so sorry for wasting your time

Comment: If you don't have a `public static void main()` how does your program run.... Where does your program "start"? Put a breakpoint there.

Comment: I guess just after public class ... { ? from there on there is different methods. I think there is a problem in my debug configuration. I've just noticed after OK it says (0 tests) it sounds like it's not doing what it is supposed to?

Comment: Without actually seeing your code or some screenshots it's impossible to say.